# excel 2013 clipboard entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, clipboard

*Sorry for missing a step between 2 & 3 on my original post. Edited portion is inserted in bold text (step 3).*

I got this excel 2013 copy-paste command problem that occurred a couple of days ago.  Here's what's happening in chrono order:

1. copied a cell from excel (cell highlight turns to broken line)
2. opened a browser (or any other program)
3. ***pasted the copied value to the browser (web based database)***
4. copied a text from the browser
5. go back to excel and invoke paste command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or right click -> Paste)
6. the value from #1 is the one being pasted and NOT the value which I copied from #4 (browser)

I tried checking the clipboard but it seems that excel could not paste the latest entry in the clipboard.

Any suggestions how to fix this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you performing two copy commands?  If the excel cell is still a broken line... it would appear the second copy did not work.

Comment: What happens if you just copy from the other program and then paste into Excel without having a copied cell in Excel first?  (i.e. skip your #1)

Comment: @wbeard52 sorry, I missed a step between 2&3 on my original post.  please see edit above in bold text.

Comment: @kazoni the copied excel value in #1 will be used to paste in the browser to search in the web based database.  a resulting value #4 in the database will then be copied and pasted to the excel.  the strange thing is when I paste the value (#4) to excel, it's pasting the value of #1 even though the clipboard already recorded the last value as #4.

Comment: How did you copy the text from the browser?  `CTRL-C` or right click and select copy?  Can you paste the web data into a different program?

Comment: @wbeard52 both CTRL-C and right click > copy does this.  yes, I could paste the web data to a different program (word, powerpoint & outlook).  It's only excel that is having the problem.  No matter how many other programs I open and paste the web data correctly when I go back to excel the "dancing" dotted line is still there and I still can't paste the web data.